# RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR issue

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle10g, ora-06512

I have developed a trigger that checks the validity of a date. It works fine because it prevents me from storing an invalid date, but I also get a weird error message and I can't figure out why. My code is the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "CHECKDATEVALIDITY" 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON Event
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF :NEW.day < 1 OR :NEW.month < 1 OR :NEW.month > 12
    THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101, 'Wrong date');
END IF;

IF :NEW.month = 4 OR :NEW.month = 6 OR :NEW.month = 9 OR :NEW.month = 11 
    THEN
        IF :NEW.day > 30
            THEN
                RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101, 'Wrong date');
        END IF;
ELSIF :NEW.month = 2
    THEN
        IF (mod(:NEW.year, 4) = 0)
            THEN
                IF :NEW.day > 29
                    THEN
                        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101, 'Wrong date');
                END IF;
        ELSIF :NEW.day > 28
            THEN
                RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101, 'Wrong date');
        END IF;
ELSE
    IF :NEW.day > 31
        THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101, 'Wrong date');
    END IF;

END IF;

END checkDateValidity;
```

The error I get is:

> error ORA-20101: Wrong date ORA-06512: on "USER587.CHECKDATEVALIDITY", line 28 ORA-04088: error while executing trigger 'USER578.CHECKDATEVALIDITY'.

Also I have noticed that I get the error from the line next to the RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR invoked. What does issue the error?

Comment: What is it that you think is "weird" about the error message?  It seems entirely appropriate to me.

Comment: Hi @p.cambell thank you for your comment. What I find weird is that the trigger works as it's supposed to do, I think there's nothing wrong with the syntax, I've checked it thoroughly and I couldn't find anything wrong with it. I don't know where to look at this point.

Comment: The problem with inventing our own logic for such common functions as date validation is that we get the rules wrong.  Years divisible by 100 are not leap years unless they are also divisible by 400.  That is, 29-FEB-1900 is a common year, 29-FEB-2000 is a leap year.  Your logic allows 29-FEB-1900, and it should not.

Comment: this is simply what `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` does -- it raises an error.  That's how the trigger prevents your update from succeeding -- by raising an error, which causes Oracle to stop processing the statement.  Note that the first code in the error stack is ORA-20101 -- the numeric value comes directly from your call to `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR`.  The code is doing exactly what you've written it to do.

Comment: Why don't you store a date as a date and let Oracle do the validation for you?  The optimizer can also do intelligent things with dates if you store them in a date datatype.

Answer (score 3):

What do you consider the "wierd error message"?  It looks like a perfectly reasonable stack trace to me.  At the bottom of the stack, you got an error executing a trigger.  The next line tells you that the error happened at line 28.  The top of the stack is your custom error message and number.  That all seems quite normal to me (though you appear to have cut off some of the error text associated with the ORA-06512 error)

```
ORA-20101: Wrong date
ORA-06512: on "USER587.CHECKDATEVALIDITY", line 28
ORA-04088: error while executing trigger 'USER578.CHECKDATEVALIDITY'.
```

If you're trying to match up the line number, take a look at `DBA_SOURCE`.  For example, this will show you what is on lines 23-32 of your trigger (the offending line +/- 5 lines).

```
SELECT line, text
  FROM dba_source
 WHERE owner = 'USER578'
   AND name  = 'CHECKDATEVALIDITY'
   AND line BETWEEN 23 and 32;
```

Of course, I assume this is a classroom exercise and not something you're doing in the real world.  In the real world, you'd store in a DATE column and let Oracle take care of ensuring that a valid date was entered.

Comment: Hi @JustinCave thank you for your answer. What I find weird is that the trigger does what it's supposed to do and I don't really understand what issues the error, I've checked over and over again the syntax and I couldn't find anything wrong with it. I'm pretty clueless.

Comment: @haunted85 - The trigger raises the error because, presumably, you're trying to insert an invalid combination of day, month, and year.  The trigger prevents the invalid data from being inserted by raising an error that causes the DML operation to fail.  That's the expected behavior.  It's also why it is extremely rare to want to validate data in a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

This means you are (by your own rules) inserting an invalid day.

Your trigger is raising ora-20101 if the day is greater than 31, and it does just that.